# what kind of attacks can be to PHP and MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, security, sql-injection

I have a website that written with php and using mysql, I want to do it maximum security as well as it can. I searched what attaks can be and I found only injection. My question is that is `mysql_real_escape_string` function provide %100 security against injection? and is there any other attacks that I should consider when writing php and mysql? thanks for helping...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520560/php-security-question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012315/php-security-best-practices

Comment: What you might wanna think of which does not concern sql and is only a concern if you use session is session hijacking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out these sources;

http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/4.html

http://segfaultlabs.com/files/pdf/php-session-security.pdf

http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross_Site_Scripting

http://www.virtualforge.de/vmovie/xss_selling_platform_v1.0.php

http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29

http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Guide_Table_of_Contents#Data_Validation

https://www.owasp.org/images/8/89/OWASP_Testing_Guide_V3.pdf

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-secxss/

http://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

http://www.owasp.org is a must. mysql_real_escape_string will not provide you 100% security.

Since you are Turkish you could also follow it here;

http://www.sanalkurs.net/forum/php-mysql/php%27de-guvenlik/

I am writing article about it whenever I find time (:

Hope this helps.